# Will this multiple inheritance code work with all compiler?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, diamond-problem

I have this code that works fine when compiled with Visual Studio.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class base
{
public:
    virtual void FOO() = 0;
};

class D1:public base
{
public:
    virtual void bar() =0;
};

class D2:public base
{
public:
    virtual void moo() =0;
};

class Impl: public D1, public D2
{
public:
    virtual void FOO()
    {}
    virtual void bar()
    {}
    virtual void moo()
    {}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Impl* p = new Impl();
    p->bar();
    p->FOO();
    base *b = (D1*)p;
    b->FOO();
    return 0;
}
```

You can see there is a diamond problem here but, I am still able to create object of `Impl` with just one definition of `FOO`. I thought I would need multiple definition coming from base classes. Can someone explain how many vtables will be created here and will compiler create multiple definition of `FOO` on its own?

I am trying to avoid virtual inheritance with the expense of extra function definition and my main point is to confirm if this would work with all compilers?

Comment: Why would you not be able to create `Impl`? As it is you can cast to `base` in two ways, but both have the same function overriding the pure virtual `FOO`.

Comment: Actually, I just want to confirm if there is anything illegal as per the standards in doing so.  I do understand that b will now use vtable of D1 and call FOO based on the entry for FOO in vtable from D1 but, will this be the case with all compiler?

Comment: Don't rely on all compilers using a vtable. But all compilers will call this function from either base.

Comment: "_You can see there is a diamond problem_" There is not. An indirect base class repeated multiple times is not a diamond problem, it is a source of potential ambiguities that can be disambiguated easily.